# Spring Native runtime error : Unsupported method java.lang.Class.isSealed() is reachable

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I am trying to execute my native image built by Spring Native and Spring Boot. Executing my app generated in the /target directory give me the following error :

```
WARN 18883 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method java.lang.Class.isSealed() is reachable: The declaring class of this element has been substituted, but this element is not present in the substitution class
ERROR 18883 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method java.lang.Class.isSealed() is reachable: The declaring class of this element has been substituted, but this element is not present in the substitution class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:258) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[clea-ws-rest:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[clea-ws-rest:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[clea-ws-rest:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[clea-ws-rest:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[clea-ws-rest:2.7.0]
        at fr.gouv.clea.ws.CleaWsRestApplication.main(CleaWsRestApplication.java:11) ~[clea-ws-rest:0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method java.lang.Class.isSealed() is reachable: The declaring class of this element has been substituted, but this element is not present in the substitution class
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:87) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.Class.isSealed(DynamicHub.java:4563) ~[clea-ws-rest:na]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:266) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.completeProxiedInterfaces(AopProxyUtils.java:146) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.<init>(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:111) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(DefaultAopProxyFactory.java:55) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport.createAopProxy(ProxyCreatorSupport.java:105) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.buildLazyResolutionProxy(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:130) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.getLazyResolutionProxyIfNecessary(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:54) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedConstructionResolver.lambda$resolve$0(InjectedConstructionResolver.java:83) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedConstructionResolver.resolveDependency(InjectedConstructionResolver.java:97) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedConstructionResolver.resolve(InjectedConstructionResolver.java:83) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedElementResolver.resolve(InjectedElementResolver.java:35) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedElementResolver.create(InjectedElementResolver.java:66) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar$BeanInstanceContext.create(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:211) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.ContextBootstrapInitializer.lambda$initialize$39(ContextBootstrapInitializer.java:378) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar$ThrowableFunction.apply(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:294) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar.lambda$instanceSupplier$0(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[na:na]
```

I use the following dependencies in my pom.xml :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aot</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

these plugins :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and these profile for building native image :

```
      <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.11</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

To build image, i use these commands lines :
`mvn package -Pnative` or `mvn package spring-boot:build-image`; then, the result appear in the /target directory, i use `./target/myApp` to run it.

Here is the result of `java --version` :

```
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 21.3.2 (build 17.0.3+7-jvmci-21.3-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 21.3.2 (build 17.0.3+7-jvmci-21.3-b14, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I found [this problem](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/3870#issue-1017685079) on github which seems very similar to mine, if not identical. The ticket has been closed but I don't understand the resolution.

The error seems to have something to do with the profiles related to the environments (dev,prod,test ...). [A section of the Spring Native documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#aot-bean-factory-preparation) is dedicated to this aspect. To solve the error, I filled in a profile in the `application.yml` configuration file. The profile is correctly loaded during the run time but the error is the same.

Wouldn't the error come from a compatibility problem between the jdk and the Spring libraries? However, [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isSealed()), the method is present since the jdk version 17.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First recommendation upgrade the native-maven-plugin to most recent version....

Comment: done, no change in the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [github issue](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/3870) that you linked we can see that the solution was to add reflection support on sealed classes in GraalVM.

This was merged to master via the [following pull request](https://github.com/oracle/graal/pull/3979).

In the [GraalVM release notes](https://www.graalvm.org/release-notes/22_0/) we can see that this made it into the releases from version `22.0.0` and higher.

> 22.0.0
> (2021-01-18)

*This date seems wrong, it's probably 2022-01-18*

> Added support for reflective introspection of sealed classes on JDK 17: Class.isSealed() and Class.getPermittedSubclasses().

Your current JDK is using GraalVM 21.3.2, so that doesn't contain this fix yet.
The solution would be to find a JDK build that has version 22.x or higher of GraalVM.